# how to send multiple requests using same client?

Tags: java, android, post, httpclient

I'm writing an android application that needs to send multiple POST requests with one `httpClient` at the same time.

in my application, a httpClient sends a login request and its session is set and the client is logged in, I want to download some pictures with the same client(that is logged in), and I want the downloads to be done at the same time, how can I do that ?

Comment: That's a bit of an odd request.  Why with the same client? and why at the same time?  Usually if you want to run multiple requests at the same time you would use multiple threads each with its own HttpClient.  At the very least you will need to change the client connection manager used so that it creates multiple connections at the same time. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Comment: @couling because I want to download some pictures simultaneously from a server and the client needs to be logged in, so I want to use one httpclient to download all the photos, how can I change the client connection manager ?

Comment: Http never guarantees to keep the same connection. Using the same connection manager here may not help.  Http servers very rarely maintain a session in this way.  Do you have any more details of this server you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Just have the login script on the server return back the image(s) data along with the successful login data, like in a json object with base64 encoded image data, decode the data to bitmaps and use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpClient createClient() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
    params.setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, true);
    params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 30 * 1000);
    params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 30 * 1000);

    SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
    schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schReg.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
    ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

    return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For executing multiple requests using the same httpclient you can use

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager conMgr =new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
httpClient = new HttpClient(conMgr);
```

`MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` allows the execution of multiple methods at once.

But you might want to configure it according to your needs.